# A time travel story where a boy explores futures

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a story that was published sometime in the 2000s, around 7 or so years old reading level.

The plot centres around a boy whose father brings home a machine that you can use to look at your future options, kind of a "pick your own path" story. Time passes a lot faster than it seems when you're in the machine, so one day he goes in to look at his possible options for his future, and when he finally finishes and decides to come out, he's already really old. The machine is in an old person's home, where his parents have been waiting for him to come out for the last sixty or so years, so he can't act upon any of the futures he saw.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember any details of the cover?  How long the story was?  Were there any illustrations?